# SQL Server 2008 R2 Transaction Counts

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, transaction

Good Afternoon,
We have a pretty big SQL Box  32proc 128gb.

We had a change in our environment, not sure what exactly change,  db/code.  We're investigating that aspect as well.   One of the things we noticed from a baseline stats were the number of transactions.   It went from 10-20K to 60-80K.

```
SELECT name, transaction_type, COUNT(1)
FROM sys.dm_tran_active_transactions
WHERE name <> 'worktable'
GROUP BY name, transaction_type

Results:
name
implicit_transaction
INSERT
sort_init
UPDATE STATISTICS
UpdateQPStats
user_transaction
LobStorageProviderSession
SELECT
sort_fake_worktable
topn_fake_worktable
workfile
WorkFileGroup_fake_worktable
```

Some of the names are self explanatory, others not so much.  I have not been able to find any of these on the web.  Does anyone have an explanation or a link where I could find the answers?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the transaction log file.  Has it increased significantly.  Also check the full transaction by query.  It will give you more detail about what was actually running.

```
/* Query to check transaction count per query and session_id */  

select er.session_id, er.request_id,
er.open_transaction_count, er.transaction_id,
at.name, at.transaction_begin_time,
REPLACE (REPLACE([text], char(13), ' '), CHAR(10), ' ') AS sql_text
from     sys.dm_exec_requests er 
join     sys.dm_tran_active_transactions at
  on     er.transaction_id = at.transaction_id
join     sys.dm_exec_query_stats stat
  on     er.plan_handle = stat.plan_handle  
CROSS
APPLY    sys.dm_exec_sql_text (stat.sql_handle)
GO

/* Check task allocation by query */

SELECT t1.session_id, t1.request_id, t1.task_alloc,
t1.task_dealloc, t2.statement_start_offset, 
t2.statement_end_offset, REPLACE (REPLACE([text], char(13), ' '), CHAR(10), ' ') AS sql_text
FROM (Select session_id, request_id,
SUM(internal_objects_alloc_page_count) AS task_alloc,
SUM (internal_objects_dealloc_page_count) AS task_dealloc 
FROM sys.dm_db_task_space_usage 
GROUP BY session_id, request_id) AS t1, 
        sys.dm_exec_requests AS t2
INNER JOIN sys.dm_exec_query_stats stat ON t2.plan_handle = stat.plan_handle
CROSS 
APPLY  sys.dm_exec_sql_text (stat.sql_handle)
WHERE  t1.session_id = t2.session_id
  AND  (t1.request_id = t2.request_id)
GO
```

Comment: Any chance you can format this code a little?  Might make it easier to read.  Thanks!

Comment: I've edited a bit for clarity.

Comment: Tempdb  log backups and data file have remained very consistent over the past 30 days.

Comment: Question regarding the top query..  One of my spids shows several rows,  that would be because of parallelism?

Comment: It could be that particular session is running multiple parallel threads, or that that session has executed that thread many times.  You can also check the sp_who (or sp_whoisactive if installed) to see if that current session is executing in parallel.